# Build Error in VC++11 Troubles - MSB3073 error code 127

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am attempting to build a project in VS Express 2012 that was not created by me on my computer for the first time and am getting the following build error:

```
error MSB3073: The command "c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "CC=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc   
CXX=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++ AR=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ar 
OBJCOPY=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-objcopy RANLIB=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib 
WINDRES=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-windres make MODEL=mdi -j "" exited with code 127.    
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets
```

I am very unfamiliar with Visual Studio make commands (and have no idea what this one is trying to do) let alone error codes and can't seem to find anywhere what exit code 127 means in relation to the MSB3073 error. I originally did not have cygwin or mingw installed on my computer and suspected that to be the issue, however after installing both I am getting the same error and I'm now out of ideas. Hopefully this is enough information to generate some thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: The 127 is the return code from bash. Looks like it's trying to build something with g++.

Comment: I am confused. You are building something in cygwin using gcc/mingw. Not Visual Studio.

Comment: Guess I'm confused too... It's a Visual Studio project and I am clicking build which is spitting out these errors. Not sure what is going on behind the scenes here with this make command and what I need to do.

Comment: That is quite an unusual visual studio project. I would ask whoever created the project for help.